# Not able to find correct Xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, robotframework, xpath-1.0

Xpath not identifying while running script in Selenium robot Framework

```
<div class="divRptData">
    <hr class="hrConnector" />
    <span style="float: left; cursor: pointer" class="tree-box tree-box-expand" onclick="javascript: toggleBranch(this, 'level2_ABC')"/>
    <span style="margin-left: 4px" class="ng-binding">text</span>
</div>
```

I already tried below XPATH for above code, which is working when I find it manually, but while running script it is not identifying.

```
//span[@onclick="javascript: toggleBranch(this, 'level2_ABC')"]

//div[3]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/span[1]
```

Can some help me out how to handle this.

Comment: Try finding the iframe in which this element present....and in code switch to this iframe first in which this element present and then try...

Comment: try this //*[local-name()='div'][@class='divRptData']/*[local-name()='span'][@onclick="javascript: toggleBranch(this, 'level2_ABC')"]

Comment: Share the HTML code.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you are suffering from quote marks problems.  Try:

```
//span[@onclick=\"javascript: toggleBranch(this, 'level2_ABC')\"]
```

You can check this XPath in your browser by typing the following in the console:

```
$x("//span[@onclick=\"javascript: toggleBranch(this, 'level2_ABC')\"]")
```

(The above works on Chrome, I think all browsers support the syntax now)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following _Xpath_s:

```
"//div[@class='divRptData']/hr[@class='hrConnector']//following::span[1]"
```

Or

```
"//div[@class='divRptData']//span[@class='tree-box tree-box-expand' and contains(@onclick, 'level2_ABC')]"
```